# circuit level parallel simulation of AES encryption using openmp

Tags: c, performance, aes, openmp, simulation

I am trying to parallelize a translated program which is in C/C++. The program was originally in Verilog hardware description language. The program has been translated into C/C++ by a translator program. The fact that it is circuit level C/C++ program should not make a difference. I am essentially trying to follow the approach in

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979872/user2979872

But

I am getting a SEGMENTATION FAULT when i try to use openmp to parallize. Here is the code. When i make "top", which is a pointer to an object private by writing #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) private(top), i get segmentation fault.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
      Verilated::commandArgs(argc, argv);
      Vaes_cipher_top* top = new Vaes_cipher_top; // this is the aes object that will do the enc
      unsigned int i = 0;
      unsigned int set_done;
      unsigned int ld_set = 0;
      top->rst = 1;           // assert reset

      #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) private(top)
       while (i < 2)
        {
              if (main_time > 10)
              {
              top->rst = 0;   // Deassert reset
              }
          if ((main_time % 10) == 1)
          {
              top->clk = 1;       // Toggle clock (posedge)
          }
          if ((main_time % 10) == 6)
          {

              top->clk = 0;
              //setting DUT values

             if(ld_set!=1 && main_time > 10)
              {
                    top -> ld = 1;
                    top -> key     =   {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                    top -> text_in =   {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                    ld_set++;
               }
              else if(ld_set == 1 && main_time > 10)
               {
                top -> ld = 0;
                 set_done = 0;
                }

            } //(main_time % 10) == 6)

            top->eval();            // Evaluate model

            if(top->done && !set_done)
            {

             print(top->key);
             print(top->text_in);
             print(top->text_out);
             ld_set = 0; //reset  
             i++;
             set_done  = 1;
            } //if(top->done)

            main_time++;            // Time passes...
        } //end of while 

        printf("\n Test Done\n");
        top->final();               // Done simulating

 delete top;

 return 0;
} //end of main
```

Trying to move forward as suggested by Hristo. No more segmentation fault but incorrect result due to race conditions.

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
  Verilated::commandArgs(argc, argv);
  Vaes_cipher_top* top;  // this is the aes object that will do the enc
  unsigned int i = 0;
  unsigned int set_done;
  unsigned int ld_set = 0;
  //top->rst = 1;           // assert reset
  unsigned int iter_count = 1;

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) firstprivate(iter_count,ld_set,set_done,i)
   while (i < 2)
    {
         if(iter_count)
          {
          top = new Vaes_cipher_top;
          iter_count = 0; 
          }
          if(main_time == 0)
            top-> rst = 1;  //assert reset
          if (main_time > 10)
          {
          top->rst = 0;   // Deassert reset
          }
      if ((main_time % 10) == 1)
      {
          top->clk = 1;       // Toggle clock (posedge)
      }
      if ((main_time % 10) == 6)
      {

          top->clk = 0;
          //setting DUT values

         if(ld_set!=1 && main_time > 10)
          {
                top -> ld = 1;
                top -> key     =   {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                top -> text_in =   {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                ld_set++;
           }
          else if(ld_set == 1 && main_time > 10)
           {
            top -> ld = 0;
             set_done = 0;
            }

        } //(main_time % 10) == 6)

        top->eval();            // Evaluate model

        if(top->done && !set_done)
        {

         print(top->key);
         print(top->text_in);
         print(top->text_out);
         ld_set = 0; //reset  
         i++;
         set_done  = 1;
         iter_count = 1; 
        } //if(top->done)

        main_time++;            // Time passes...
    } //end of while 

    printf("\n Test Done\n");
    top->final();               // Done simulating

     delete top;

return 0;
} //end of main
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

updated as suggested by Hristo to move the declaration Vaes_cipher_top *top inside the while loop

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
 {
  Verilated::commandArgs(argc, argv);
  unsigned int i = 0;
  unsigned int set_done;
  unsigned int ld_set = 0;
  //top->rst = 1;           // assert reset
  unsigned int iter_count = 1;

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) firstprivate(iter_count,ld_set,set_done,i)
   while (i < 2)
    {
         if(iter_count)
          {
          Vaes_cipher_top* top;  // this is the aes object that will do the enc
          top = new Vaes_cipher_top;
          iter_count = 0; 
          }
          if(main_time == 0)
            top-> rst = 1;  //assert reset
          if (main_time > 10)
          {
          top->rst = 0;   // Deassert reset
          }
      if ((main_time % 10) == 1)
      {
          top->clk = 1;       // Toggle clock (posedge)
      }
      if ((main_time % 10) == 6)
      {

          top->clk = 0;
          //setting DUT values

         if(ld_set!=1 && main_time > 10)
          {
                top -> ld = 1;
                top -> key     =   {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                top -> text_in =   {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                ld_set++;
           }
          else if(ld_set == 1 && main_time > 10)
           {
            top -> ld = 0;
             set_done = 0;
            }

        } //(main_time % 10) == 6)

        top->eval();            // Evaluate model

        if(top->done && !set_done)
        {

         print(top->key);
         print(top->text_in);
         print(top->text_out);
         ld_set = 0; //reset  
         i++;
         set_done  = 1;
         iter_count = 1; 
        } //if(top->done)

        main_time++;            // Time passes...
    } //end of while 

    printf("\n Test Done\n");
    top->final();               // Done simulating

     delete top;

return 0;
} //end of main
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Here is the output. All the errors are the same. I am putting a few of them

./sim_main.cpp:76: error: ‘top’ was not declared in this scope ( on line where top->rst=1)
../sim_main.cpp:80: error: ‘top’ was not declared in this scope (on line where top->rst=0)
../sim_main.cpp:84: error: ‘top’ was not declared in this scope (on line  where top->clk =1)
../sim_main.cpp:89: error: ‘top’ was not declared in this scope (on line  where top->clk=0)

If you remove the if surrounding the Vaes_cipher_top declartion, it becomes infinite loop!!!
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Simulation hangs and output appears at different times on every run. I am using 2 threads i.e, num_threads(2)

```
    (1) This is the run where simulation terminates

key=67fd3c2821b9201521d6a87f205e3039
text_in=67fd3c2821b9201521d6a87f205e3039
Time=251,text_out=71a354729996bac975784dcdb50260d9, done= 1 on  0 of  2
i= 1
key=1a857b7f39a0290d20bbf2466b5b14e8
text_in=1a857b7f39a0290d20bbf2466b5b14e8
Time=321,text_out=da36095f53fd86a57f9d147e8e05603, done= 1 on  1 of  2
i= 1
key=67fd3c2821b9201521d6a87f205e3039
text_in=67fd3c2821b9201521d6a87f205e3039
Time=401,text_out=71a354729996bac975784dcdb50260d9, done= 1 on  0 of  2
i= 2
key=1a857b7f39a0290d20bbf2466b5b14e8
text_in=1a857b7f39a0290d20bbf2466b5b14e8
Time=601,text_out=da36095f53fd86a57f9d147e8e05603, done= 1 on  1 of  2
i= 2
key=67fd3c2821b9201521d6a87f205e3039
text_in=67fd3c2821b9201521d6a87f205e3039
Time=641,text_out=71a354729996bac975784dcdb50260d9, done= 1 on  0 of  2
i= 3
key=1a857b7f39a0290d20bbf2466b5b14e8
text_in=1a857b7f39a0290d20bbf2466b5b14e8
Time=841,text_out=da36095f53fd86a57f9d147e8e05603, done= 1 on  1 of  2
i= 3
key=67fd3c2821b9201521d6a87f205e3039
text_in=67fd3c2821b9201521d6a87f205e3039
Time=911,text_out=71a354729996bac975784dcdb50260d9, done= 1 on  0 of  2
i= 4
key=1a857b7f39a0290d20bbf2466b5b14e8
text_in=1a857b7f39a0290d20bbf2466b5b14e8
Time=991,text_out=da36095f53fd86a57f9d147e8e05603, done= 1 on  1 of  2
i= 4

 Test Done

    (2) This is the RUN where simulation DOES NOT terminate and i had to press ctrl+c   
        to abort the simulation

    key=75f1bcf47451ab0f33b58a5e1adfdd6
text_in=75f1bcf47451ab0f33b58a5e1adfdd6
Time=411,text_out=9049c33819d61de5c09aa388479ef10, done= 1 on  0 of  2
i= 1
key=75f1bcf47451ab0f33b58a5e1adfdd6
text_in=75f1bcf47451ab0f33b58a5e1adfdd6
Time=696,text_out=9049c33819d61de5c09aa388479ef10, done= 1 on  0 of  2
i= 2
key=75f1bcf47451ab0f33b58a5e1adfdd6
text_in=75f1bcf47451ab0f33b58a5e1adfdd6
Time=931,text_out=9049c33819d61de5c09aa388479ef10, done= 1 on  0 of  2
i= 3
key=75f1bcf47451ab0f33b58a5e1adfdd6
text_in=75f1bcf47451ab0f33b58a5e1adfdd6
Time=1151,text_out=9049c33819d61de5c09aa388479ef10, done= 1 on  0 of  2
i= 4
^C
```

(Had to press Ctrl+c to abort the simulation. Only 1 core is being used instead
of 2, Why is this happening and how to prevent that from happening? Why is output
of two threads NOT appearing at the same time? Can this be done?

Please click the button 
add / show 1 more comment 
at the bottom of this webpage to see new comments

Thanks

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Here is the final working code that i want to share with everybody
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <omp.h>
#include "Vaes_cipher_top.h"
#include "verilated.h"
#include "verilated_vcd_c.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



  //#pragma omp threadprivate(top)

vluint64_t main_time = 0;       // Current simulation time
 // This is a 64-bit integer to reduce wrap over issues and
 // allow modulus.  You can also use a double, if you wish.

  double sc_time_stamp ()
{       // Called by $time in Verilog
       return main_time;           // converts to double, to match
                                              // what SystemC does
 }



int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) 
{
      Verilated::commandArgs(argc, argv);
      srand(time(NULL));


          unsigned int set_done = 0;
          unsigned int i = 0;
          unsigned int ld_set = 0;

    #ifdef OMP
      #pragma omp parallel default(none) firstprivate(i,set_done,ld_set,main_time)
      {
          // unsigned int set_done = 0;
          // unsigned int i = 0;
          // unsigned int ld_set = 0; 
           Vaes_cipher_top* top = new Vaes_cipher_top;  // this is the aes object that will do the enc
           top->rst = 1;           // assert reset
    #endif

        while (i < 65000)
       // #pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(static) 
       // for(i=0; (i<65000);i++)   
        {

              if (main_time > 10)
              {
                  top->rst = 0;   // Deassert reset
              }
              if ((main_time % 10) == 1)
              {
                  top->clk = 1;       // Toggle clock (posedge)
              }
              if ((main_time % 10) == 6)
              {

                  top->clk = 0;
                  //setting DUT values

              if(ld_set!=1 && main_time > 10)
               {
                  top -> ld = 1;

                  //unsigned int rand_state = time(NULL) + 1337*omp_get_thread_num();
                  //unsigned int rnd[4];      
                  //rnd[0] = rand_r(&rand_state);
                  //rnd[1] = rand_r(&rand_state);
                  //rnd[2] = rand_r(&rand_state);
                  //rnd[3] = rand_r(&rand_state);
                  top -> key     =   {rand(),rand(),rand(),rand()}; // {0x00000000,0x000000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                  top -> text_in =   {rand(),rand(),rand(),rand()}; //{0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};  
                  //top -> key     =   {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                  //top -> text_in =   {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
                  ld_set++;
                }
                else if(ld_set == 1 && main_time > 10)
                {
                top -> ld = 0;
                set_done = 0;
                }   

                } //(main_time % 10) == 6)

                top->eval();            // Evaluate model

                if(top->done == 1 && set_done == 0)
                {
                #ifdef OMP
                   printf("Time=%2d, key=%2x%2x%2x%2x,text_in=%2x%2x%2x%2x,text_out=%2x%2x%2x%2x on %2d of %2d\n",   \
                           main_time,top->key[3],top->key[2],top->key[1],top->key[0],                               \
                           top->text_in[3],top->text_in[2],top->text_in[1],top->text_in[0],                 \
                           top->text_out[3],top->text_out[2],top->text_out[1],top->text_out[0],top->done, \
                           omp_get_thread_num(),omp_get_num_threads()
                         );
                #else
                   printf("Time=%2d, key=%2x%2x%2x%2x,text_in=%2x%2x%2x%2x,text_out=%2x%2x%2x%2x\n" ,   \
                           main_time,top->key[3],top->key[2],top->key[1],top->key[0],                               \
                           top->text_in[3],top->text_in[2],top->text_in[1],top->text_in[0],                 \
                           top->text_out[3],top->text_out[2],top->text_out[1],top->text_out[0],top->done
                         );
                #endif

                  ld_set = 0; //reset the value 
                    i++;
                  // printf("i=%2d\n",i);
                   set_done  = 1;
                } //if(top->done)

                //#pragma omp barrier   
                main_time++;

          } //end of while


        top->final();               // Done simulating
        delete top;
      } //pragma omp

        printf("\n Test Done\n");


    return 0;
} //end of main
```

Comment: `private(top)` doesn't make the object pointed by `top` private but rather the pointer itself. Each thread ends up with an uninitialised private pointer and any attempt to dereference such a pointer with `->` ends up in a segmentation fault. How about you move the `Vaes_cipher_top* top = new Vaes_cipher_top;` statement inside the parallel loop? Some variables look like they too need the `private` treatment. Also, each thread executes the same `while` loop and the work is not distributed among the threads. Are you testing if `Vaes_cipher_top` is thread-safe?

Comment: Hi Hristo, Thanks for your comment again. I am not testing if Vaes_cipher_top is thread-safe, i just want to make it multithreaded. Secondly, i have coded the while loop as you see so that each thread does the same work. Once each thread produces the correct result, i shall put random number generation for key and plaintext so that each thread works on separate plaintext and key. Right now things are not working. Please see modified code above

Comment: You moved only the `new` statement inside the parallel region but left the definition of `top` outside and it is still shared.

Comment: You get scoping errors like ./sim_main.cpp:76: error: ‘top’ was not declared in this scope. See above for updated code and error messages

Comment: Hristo, just to let you know. I shall acknowledge your contribution in helping me out in the source code. Also this code will be made opensource for anyone to use.

Comment: updated the above section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right, but `Vaes_cipher_top* top;` should be moved before the `if` statement, e.g. immediately after the opening brace of the `while` loop. Also in this case `top` would not be visible outside the parallel region. I would suggest that you restructure the code as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
   Verilated::commandArgs(argc, argv);

   #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
   {
      unsigned int i = 0;
      unsigned int set_done;
      unsigned int ld_set = 0;
      //top->rst = 1;           // assert reset
      unsigned int iter_count = 1;
      Vaes_cipher_top* top = new Vaes_cipher_top;  // this is the aes object that will do the enc

      while (i < 2)
      {
         if (iter_count)
         {
            top = new Vaes_cipher_top;
            iter_count = 0; 
         }
         if (main_time == 0)
            top-> rst = 1;  //assert reset
         if (main_time > 10)
         {
            top->rst = 0;   // Deassert reset
         }
         if ((main_time % 10) == 1)
         {
            top->clk = 1;       // Toggle clock (posedge)
         }
         if ((main_time % 10) == 6)
         {
            top->clk = 0;
            //setting DUT values

            if (ld_set!=1 && main_time > 10)
            {
               top->ld = 1;
               top->key     = {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
               top->text_in = {0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000};
               ld_set++;
            }
            else if (ld_set == 1 && main_time > 10)
            {
               top->ld = 0;
               set_done = 0;
            }
         } //(main_time % 10) == 6)

         top->eval();            // Evaluate model

         if (top->done && !set_done)
         {
            print(top->key);
            print(top->text_in);
            print(top->text_out);
            ld_set = 0; //reset  
            i++;
            set_done  = 1;
            iter_count = 1; 
         } //if(top->done)

         main_time++;            // Time passes...
      } //end of while 

      top->final();               // Done simulating

      delete top;
   }

   printf("\nTest Done\n");

   return 0;
} //end of main
```

Though this has nothing to do with OpenMP, the above code leaks memory. `top` is being allocated anew each time when `iter_count` is non-zero, which happens when the `if (top->done && !set_done)` conditional is true and `i` is still equal to `0`. Probably you should think about how to remedy that problem.

Comment: Let me try that code.I should get back to you in an hour with an update. Thanks so so much.

Comment: Hristo dude! It IS working. Hooray!!! First of all my heartfelt thanks to you and to the stackoverflow community for making such a marvelous and friendly platform available. I am going to put your name in the source code and make it opensource soon. I shall keep you posted. If it is possible for you to email me your contact, you can be posted about the open source code. Thanks again

Comment: I am noticing one thing in the simulation and that is simulation hangs sometimes. Also when i re-run the simulation, the cipher text appears on different times on every run. See above for an example. How to remedy this

Comment: Simulation hangs when i add randomization for plaintext and key. If i don't add randomization and let the key and plaintext to be 0 as shown above in your solution, simulation does not hang most of the time. But once in 5 runs, it still hangs with plaintext and key being 0. While in case of plaintext and key being random, it hangs most of the time like 8 in 10 runs.

Comment: Does it hang when run in serial mode, e.g. with `num_threads(1)` or with OpenMP disabled during compilation?

Comment: Hi Hristo, It does not hang in serial mode or with num_threads(1). The problem seems to be this statment if (top->done && !set_done). If i modify this to if (top->done), then simulation does not hang. What are your thoughts and inside view?

Comment: It could be an error in your state logic or it could be the case that `class Vaes_cipher_top` has some static data members, which makes it unusable in concurrent scenarios like this one.

Comment: Hi Hristo, I have observed that with for loop, this situation does not happen. The problem with for loop is that it increments no matter what. On the other hand, with while loop, you can control when to increment i. What do you think?

Comment: Found the problem. These variables have to be first_private i.e., firstprivate(i,set_done,ld_set,main_time)